# Xcode writing to file in a unit test

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, swift

I understand that when a unit test executes, it is in the sandbox environment of Xcode.
In a unit test, I need to write and read data to a file.
Since the project resides in a git repository, this must be done completely from within code (i.e. no special manual test setup of directories is possible)

For all my searching and trying today, I cannot find a way to write to a file from within the unit test.

Does anybody know of a method to write to a file under these conditions?

Edit: This is the problematic code:

```
let dirPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()!

var filePath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("unittest.json")

if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().isWritableFileAtPath(filePath) {
    return (nil, "Directory missing or write access not granted for \(path)")
}
```

Comment: What are your test requirements? Does the file actually need to exist on the disk, or could mock the file manager and return true when the file has been written?

Comment: I need to read the contents back. If all else fails, I will mock the thing, but I am hoping that this is not necessary.

Comment: Wel, this is why we do unit testing :-) The error is in the use of "isWriteableFileAtPath", this function needs a file to exist at the given path. It does not check if a file can be created at the given path. So the error was not in the unit test, but in the code, a relief ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the temporary directory: `NSTemporaryDirectory()` and have it reliably point to a safe place to read and write.  I'd suggest making sure you clean up any created files.

```
let dirPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()
```

To see whether a file can be created (per the updated question), check the directory for write permissions:

```
let canCreate = NSFileManager.defaultManager().isWritableFileAtPath(dirPath)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Or anyone else for that matter? It does not work for me. I am now suspecting that something else may be wrong, after all, I am still testing... I have updated the original question to show the code that produces the error.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this answer as it is probably the best way to do this. Even though this was not the solution.